How do I minify my HTML so that CSS and FontAwesome and Bootstrap names are reduced
I have a Django website that displays a table with data. It uses FontAwesome and Bootstrap for styling - which leads to some lengthy HTML (a standard page is 136k).
Eg Some TDs contain an arrow using FA and a style to rotate it eg
<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down fa-lg fa-rotate-by" style=--fa-rotate-angle:282deg></i>

Is there a way to minify or some how reduce the name sizes?
I have been reading about webpack and gulp minifiers but I cannot find anything that mentions the use of 3rd party assets like FA and BS and how one might reduce their name sizes.  Also these seem somewhat targeted to client-side frameworks rather than server-side which mine is.


By HTML Minification
 - pip install htmlmin
 - MIDDLEWARE = ['path.to.minify_middleware.Minify',]



from htmlmin.minify import html_minify #import minify
class Minify:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response =get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    if "text/html" in response.get('Content-Type', ''):
        response.content = html_minify(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    return response

   


Thanks. I'm already using django-strip-whitespace - which reduces from 215k to 139k . I've just checked out the htmlmin docs but it doesnt say what it actually does - do you know if it does another other than remove whitespace?

Alternatively, by HTTP compression, if the intent is not to obfusticate your code at the browser end but to reduce bandwidth consumed. Django comes with gzip middleware, or there's django-compression-middleware. which suppports other compression methods.
I believe, but haven't measured, that HTTP compression will save more bandwidth than minification. It's also install-and-forget. You can of course do both.

Thanks. I am already using gzip (via my production nginx server) and also django-strip-whitespace which together reduce the size from 215lk to 9.5k.  But when I do a view source.. I still see a huge amount of, IMO, is excess characters taken up with long names.
